# A notation for distinctness (in logic)

Tags: logic, notation

I want to say formally that $C_0$, ..., $C_{n+1}$ are distinct. Two ways seem to be

(1) $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (\forall x,y \in \Bbb N)(x \ne y \to C_x \ne C_y)$,

(2) $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad C_{0 \le i \le n} \space \ne \space C_{i+(1 \le j \le n+1)}$.

Are (1) and (2) interchangable, assuming (the likely obvious) that $i, j, n \in \Bbb N$? And is there a better way?

Comment: (1) is more used (except that you may want to restrict your $i$ and $j$ to $\{0,1, \ldots ,n+1\}$, (2)'s notation is a bit ambiguous. Another way can be to say $$\forall \, i,j \in \{0, \ldots, n+1\} \quad C_i=C_j \iff i=j.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to say it symbolically (keep in mind that in most cases it's better to just write precisely in natural language), a useful notation is *indexed conjunctions*, the $\wedge$-analogue of $\sum$: we write "$\bigwedge_{i\in I}\alpha_i$" to denote that $\alpha_i$ is true for each $i\in I$. (Similarly, we have $\bigvee$ for disjunctions.)

And we can further fold abbreviations into the subscript, just as we do for $\sum$; so the proposition $$\bigwedge_{0\le i<j\le n+1}C_i\not=C_j$$ does the job. (Of course there's an implicit assumption that $i,j$ range over naturals, but this is standard here.)